# How do I convert binary UTF-8 string to string?

Tags: string, binary, erlang

Is it possible to convert Erlang binary UTF-8 string (like `<<"HELLO">>`) to lowercase without converting it to list and back?

Comment: This library: https://github.com/erlang-unicode/ux.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you know how to lowercase unicode character and key words here are "without converting it to list and back", then the answer could be:

```
<< <<(unicode_to_lower(C))/utf8>> || <<C/utf8>> <= <<"HELLO">> >>.
```

Comment: @Kay: Having a working implementation of `unicode_to_lower/1` is implied by the answer.

Comment: I knew I am missing something really simple! Thanks!

Comment: Note: This will only work on a very small subset (the ASCII range)! For some "values" You have to peek at the following bytes (I think up to 6 bytes). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Comment: @bsmr It will work not just for ASCII `1> [ C || <<C/utf8>> <= unicode:characters_to_binary("ПРИВЕТ") ].
[1055,1056,1048,1042,1045,1058]
`

Answer (score 11):

[string:lowercase](http://erlang.org/doc/man/string.html#lowercase-1) in Erlang 20 works with binaries:

```
1> string:lowercase(<<"HELLO">>).
<<"hello">>
```